# Navigate to item 3 from item 1 in Panorama View

Tags: windows-phone, longlistselector, panorama-control

I have a panorama app and I want navigate to item 3 from item 1, When the user clicks a button at item 1 panorama but I don't know how to do this. I have searched but nothing.

I am using Long list selector to write the contents in the List.

How can i do This ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this may help :
writing extra words to fill up thirty characters, i really dont need to write anything
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aschapiro/archive/2012/07/21/navigating-directly-to-a-specific-screen-inside-a-panorama-or-pivot-page.aspx